# How do you set a frame (awt)'s size to fullscreen in a simple java statement?

Tags: java, awt, frame, fullscreen, maximize-window

I would like to set my frame automatically to fullscreen.  Is this possible, and if yes how?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to maximize your frame use:

```
frame.setExtendedState(Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
```

If you want the frame to have no decoration (truly fullscreen) use this aswell:

```
frame.setUndecorated(true);
```